# Function that finds the last occurance of a range and returns "1"

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula

[image: sample picture]

Attached is a sample idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. Basically I need the last occurance of the order_id to return shipped_status of 1 otherwise leave it as 0.

Even better if this function can handle doing this with an unsorted order_id list

Comment: Are they always sorted like your example?  If so: `=--(A2<>A3)`  IF not `=--(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2)=COUNTIFS(A$1:A2,A2))`

Comment: I can always sort before doing the function, but it would be preferred if I can get a function working with an unsorted list then it would save doing that extra step

Comment: Or : `=--(iserror(match(A2,A3:A$1040000,0)))` for unsorted.  This will be quicker than the countifs version.